# How does StackExchange deliver changes to pages if background sync if off?

Tags: browser, background-sync

I happen to keep background sync on my browser off yet, the changes that occur to a page on StackOverflow appear on the page on the top like it usually used to, you know the *"An edit has been made to this post"* banner at the top.

**(Edited)** That made me wonder about two things:-

1. How does StackExchange sends the information to the end-user about changes that occur on a page even with background sync off?
2. What really happens when I turn off the background sync in my web browser? Does it completely block any requests made to the server or something else is the matter?

Note: My browser is Google Chrome version 74.0 on a 32-bit Windows 7.

Comment: Background sync has nothing to do with what you experience with StackOverflow. It is meant to delay sending messages in the background until the connection is stable. SO page updates are AJAX.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi So, all that background sync does is delay requests to fetch changes to the page instead of completely blocking them till the user presses the refresh button or reloads the page in some way?

Comment: Yes, roughly speaking.